# How can I use Coalesce and Max to extract maximum valued column which is not null

Tags: sql, null, max, impala, coalesce

I have columns `A, B, C and D` and would like to create new calculated column with `MAX(COLUMN_A, COLUMN_B)/MAX(COLUMN_C, COLUMN_D)`.

Some of the rows in these columns also have NULL values, How Can I do this in Impala or SQL

[image]

Comment: Add some sample table data (incl null's and 0's) and the expected result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `least()` and `greatest()` for this purpose.  Ignoring `NULL`:

```
select greatest(a, b) / greatest(c, d)
```

The problem are the `NULL` values.  I think these functions return `NULL` if any argument is `NULL`.  If the values are known to be positive, you can replace `NULL` with 0:

```
select greatest(coalesce(a, 0), coalesce(b, 0)) / greatest(coalesce(c, 0), coalesce(d, 0))
```

Or, with two values, you can use this construct:

```
select greatest(coalesce(a, b), coalesce(b, a)) / greatest(coalesce(c, d), coalesce(d, c))
```

Comment: Only caveat to `select greatest(coalesce(a, 0), coalesce(b, 0)) / greatest(coalesce(c, 0), coalesce(d, 0))` is that the values in the columns are all positive numbers. Only caveat to `select greatest(coalesce(a, b), coalesce(b, a)) / greatest(coalesce(c, d), coalesce(d, c))` is that not all columns are nullable.

Comment: @Peter4499 . . . That means that either solution should work in your case, although you might want to be careful about divide-by-zero.